# Using awk/find to output result and file name

Tags: bash, awk, find

Example data in three files.

**fileOne.txt**

```
YYY >>
 yyy one
 yyy two
 yyy three
<<

ZZZ >>
 zzz one
 zzz two
 zzz three
<<
```

**fileTwo.txt**

```
XXX >>
 xxx one
 xxx two
 xxx three
<<
```

**fileThree.txt**

```
XXX >>
 xxx one
 xxx two
 xxx three
<<

ZZZ >>
 zzz one
 zzz two
 zzz three
<<
```

I am using awk to output portions of the file between start delimiter (**XXX**) and end delimiter (**<<**). This works:

```
awk '/XXX/,/<</' /d/Temp/temp/*.txt
```

**Results**

```
XXX >>
 xxx one
 xxx two
 xxx three
<<
XXX >>
 xxx one
 xxx two
 xxx three
<<
```

But I want to output the file names too. Find sort of works, but it ends out printing **all** the file names.

```
find /d/Temp/temp/ -type f -name "*.txt" -print -exec awk '/XXX/,/<</' {} \;
```

**Results**

```
/d/Temp/temp/fileOne.txt
/d/Temp/temp/fileThree.txt
XXX >>
 xxx one
 xxx two
 xxx three
<<
/d/Temp/temp/fileTwo.txt
XXX >>
 xxx one
 xxx two
 xxx three
<<
```

How can I modify this command to only output the matched file names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using awk

```
awk '/XXX/,/<</{print a[FILENAME]?$0:FILENAME RS $0;a[FILENAME]++}' *.txt
```

Explanation:

```
/XXX/,/<</                      # output portions of the file between start delimiter (XXX) and end delimiter (<<). 
a[FILENAME]?                    # assign filename as key to array `a`, determine whether it is the true (>0) or fails (0 or null)
a[FILENAME]?$0:FILENAME RS $0   # if true, print the line only, if fail, print filename and the current line
a[FILENAME]++                   # increase the value of array a[FILENAME]
```

Comment: +1 As always for the short one line `awk` (can also be made recursive by just doing `**/*.txt` with globstar). Can you briefly explain the logic it uses in your answer.

Comment: I have added the explanation.

Comment: I wanted to use this in a script, so I also needed to escape $ in the awk command part so that I could use positional parameters: `awk "/${1}/,/<</{print a[FILENAME]?\$0:FILENAME RS \$0;a[FILENAME]++}" ~/tmp/*.txt`

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure someone will come up with a clever solution with `find` and `exec` or `xargs`, but this can be pretty simply done using just `bash` and `awk`.

```
> for file in /d/Temp/temp/*.txt; do res=$(awk '/XXX/,/<</' "$file"); [[ $res != "" ]] && echo "$file" && echo "$res"; done
/d/Temp/temp/fileThree.txt
XXX >>
 xxx one
 xxx two
 xxx three
<<
/d/Temp/temp/fileTwo.txt
XXX >>
 xxx one
 xxx two
 xxx three
<<
```

Or split into a more reasonable looking shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in "/d/Temp/temp/"*.txt; do 
  res=$(awk '/XXX/,/<</' "$file")
  [[ $res != "" ]] && echo "$file" && echo "$res" 
done
```

If you want it to be recursive and are using bash 4+, you can replace the starting for loop with

```
> shopt -s globstar; for file in /d/Temp/temp/**/*.txt; do
```

If you are using an older version of bash, you can replace it with a `find` loop

```
> find /d/Temp/temp/ -type f -name "*.txt" -print0 | while read -r -d '' file; do
```