# Use awk to output section of file forward and back from target regex

Tags: regex, bash, awk

This is an extension to [Using awk/find to output result and file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21273862/using-awk-find-to-output-result-and-file-name), where I found out how to use awk to output a file name and a section of the file matched by start and end regex.

So if I had a file **fileThree.txt** with contents

```
XXX >>
 xxx one
 xxx two
 xxx three
<<

ZZZ >>
 zzz one
 zzz two
 zzz three
<<
```

Then this command:

```
awk '/XXX/,/<</{print a[FILENAME]?$0:FILENAME RS $0;a[FILENAME]++}' *.txt
```

would output

```
/d/Temp/temp/fileTwo.txt
XXX >>
 xxx one
 xxx two
 xxx three
<<
```

I love this and am using it daily, but I wanted to extend it a bit further, and haven't worked out how. Essentially I want say "search for x between y and z, outputting all lines between (and including the lines) y to z".

So, I want to search for "xxx two" and get everything within that "block" starting from the line with ">>" and ending with the line with "<<" - i.e. it would have exactly the same output as the above.

---

**Update**: Friday 31 January 2014, 03:53:29 PM

Showing result of @Endoro's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21472286/257233), which doesn't quite output correctly. Command:

```
awk '/xxx one/{f=7};/>>/{delete(s)};{s[++i]=$0};/<</&&f {print FILENAME;for (j in s) print s[j];f=0}' *.txt
```

Output:

```
fileThree.txt
 xxx three
<<
XXX >>
 xxx one
 xxx two
fileTwo.txt
XXX >>
 xxx one
 xxx two
 xxx three
<<
```

---

**Update**: Sunday 4 February 2014

In response to @EdMorton's answer, that these files are just examples and that the general format is that "records" start with any line that ends with ">>" and ends with any line that just contains "<<". It means that records can contain blank lines.

---

**Update**: Monday 3 February 2014, 11:49:22 AM

In reviewing @EdMorton's answer, I have devised my solution which is used in a script in this way:

```
# Set these based on input arguments.
ignoreCase=
searchTerm=
directory=
# Then do the search
gawk -v RS='\n<<\n+' "BEGIN{IGNORECASE=$ignoreCase} /${searchTerm}/{print FILENAME ORS \$0 ORS \"<<\"}" "${directory}"/*.txt | less -I -p "$searchTerm"
```

Comment: Never use range expressions (e.g. `/XXX/,/<</`) to find a block of text. They make the trivial solutions slightly briefer but then require a complete re-write and/or duplication of conditions for anything even slightly more complicated. Always just set a flag instead (e.g. `/XXX/{f=1} f; /<</{f=0}`). The only exception to that is when you want to find the LAST end delimiter in the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the input format you posted, the way to get the output you want with awk is:

```
awk -v RS= '/xxx two/{print FILENAME ORS $0}' file
```

See:

```
$ cat file
XXX >>
 xxx one
 xxx two
 xxx three
<<

ZZZ >>
 zzz one
 zzz two
 zzz three
<<
$
$ awk -v RS= '/xxx two/{print FILENAME ORS $0}' file
file
XXX >>
 xxx one
 xxx two
 xxx three
<<
```

Alternatively, given the info in your updated question that records can contain blank lines, using GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ gawk -v RS='\n<<\n+' '/xxx two/{print FILENAME ORS $0 ORS "<<"}' file
file
XXX >>
 xxx one
 xxx two
 xxx three
<<
```

or (take your pick):

```
$ gawk -v RS='\n<<' '/xxx two/{sub(/^\n+/,""); print FILENAME ORS $0 RT}' file
file
XXX >>
 xxx one
 xxx two
 xxx three
<<
```

or if you don't really have blank lines between records or do have them but don't care if they are reproduced in the output:

```
$ gawk -v RS='\n<<\n' '/xxx two/{printf "%s", FILENAME ORS $0 RT}' file
file
XXX >>
 xxx one
 xxx two
 xxx three
<<
```

By the way, IF you had to do this with non-gawk then you have 2 main choices:

1) map your real RS to a single char:

```
$ awk '{sub(/<</,SUBSEP)}1' file | awk -v f=file 'BEGIN{RS=SUBSEP} /xxx two/{print f ORS $0 "<<"}'
file
XXX >>
 xxx one
 xxx two
 xxx three
<<
```

2) or create the string for your record by concatenating lines, e.g.:

```
$ awk '{rec = rec $0 ORS} /^<</{ if (rec ~ /xxx two/) printf "%s", FILENAME ORS rec; rec=""}' file
file
XXX >>
 xxx one
 xxx two
 xxx three
<<
```

Either way, you don't need to build up an array, set flags, loop, etc. - always just identify/create the records and do an RE comparison on each record.

Comment: Yes, it's important to remember that awk is record-oriented, not line-oriented like sed, so when you see someone ask how to find a block of text the first thing that should spring to mind is s/block/record/ and then look for the record separators. If it wasn't blank lines in this case, it'd be `<<`. In either case it would not be necessary to build up an array or string of lines - just identify the record separator and search for the target string or RE within each record.

Comment: I see, this is nice, but doesn't fit my use case - I have specifically set up my notes file to use >> and << as the delimiters, not empty lines. I am sorry that I did not include that in my examples.

Comment: If your posted sample input doesn't represent your real input, you should update your sample input to better represent your real input (including edge cases like << and >> on 1 line, or 2 consecutive lines or anything else you can imagine might be hard to deal with) so we can help you, otherwise we're just guessing.

Comment: I updated my answer to show how to use `<<` as a record separator but again, I'm just basing it on your posted input.

Comment: I am really impressed with @EdMorton, thank you. Would you mind explaining this one a little more: `gawk -v RS='\n<<\n+' '/xxx two/{print FILENAME ORS $0 ORS "<<"}' file`? Specifically, how is working without knowing that ">>" indicates the starting line of a record?

Comment: And how to make it case insensitive? I am having trouble working out how to integrate IGNORECASE=1 into the command.

Comment: It doesn't know or care that `>>` indicates the start of a record, it knows that records are SEPARATED by `\n<<\n++`. If you had anything except blank lines between each closing `<<` and the next opening `>>` line then we'd need to tweak the script but you don't. To make it case insensitive just change `/xxx two/` to `tolower($0) ~ /xxx two/` or add `BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1}`.

Answer (score 1):

you might test this with [gawk](/questions/tagged/gawk):

```
awk '/xxx one/{f=7};/>>/{delete(s)};{s[++i]=$0};/<</&&f {print FILENAME;for (j in s) print s[j];f=0}' *.txt
```

---

To get an ordered output, see @EdMorton's comment:

```
awk '/zzz one/{f=7}/>>/{delete(s);i=0}{s[++i]=$0}/<</&&f {print FILENAME;for (j=1;j<=i;j++) print s[j];f=0}' *.txt
```

Comment: No, that didn't output correctly.. hmm, cannot put multi-line comments, so I can't add the output here.

Comment: Double checked: http://i.imgur.com/uxASPG3.png. I am using Cygwin on WinXp if this matters.

Comment: @RobertMarkBram I'm using `GNU awk` v4.1.0 on Windows 8 and I don't know, what's going on [screen](http://img716.imageshack.us/img716/740/wub2.png)

Comment: I truly appreciate the effort you put into this, and am perfectly willing to accept I am somehow doing it wrong! :/

Comment: `for (j in s)` will output the lines in each record in a random order so different people will see different results. Reset `i` with `s` and use `for (j=1; j in s; j++)` or `for (j=1; j<=i; j++)` instead. Note that this solution is gawk-specific due to `delete array` and you don't need the spurious `;`s after each action block.

Answer (score 1):

I was working on this when Endoro submitted.  I think this is a little more readable on multiple lines.  The main difference between Endoro's solution and this one - this one keeps the order of the read in lines and discards matched blocks that don't contain the search text:

```
#!/bin/sh

awk '/>>/ { p=1 }
p     { a[i++]=$0; if(/xxx two/) m=1 }
/<</  {
    if(m) {
        print FILENAME
        for( j=0; j<i; j++ ) { print a[j] }
        m=0
    }
    p=0; i=0; delete a
}' $*
```

By awk blocks, it's basically:

- start the pattern
- store the line in an "indexed" array when "in the block", if the block matches, set a flag
- at the end of the pattern, print out the array in order, then reset the variables and clear the array

Here's the "one-line" version with the extra `;`s

```
awk '/>>/ {p=1} p {a[i++]=$0; if(/xxx two/) m=1} /<</{if(m){print FILENAME; for(j=0;j<i;j++) {print a[j]} m=0 } p=0; i=0; delete a}' *.txt
```

Comment: I don't see ">>" in there, so not sure how it would know where to start the output from? When I put that in a script and ran it, it appears to hang.

Comment: Sorry - copy/paste error.  I was original using `/XXX/` from the prior example.  I've updated the answer.

Comment: Brilliant! Again, I wanted to put this in a script, so I am using it like this: `awk "/>>/ {p=1} p {a[i++]=\$0; if(/${@}/) m=1} /<</{if(m){print FILENAME; for(j=0;j<i;j++) {print a[j]} m=0 } p=0; i=0; delete a}" *.txt`

Comment: And it's so fast.. before my last post, I was using grep in my own scripts doing similar (but not as powerful) work for years, and on my big note files they were rather slow - but awk is blazingly *fast*.

Comment: awk arrays by convention and in all builtin functions start at 1, not zero, so you should be using `++i` as your index and looping `(j=1;j<=i;j++)`. You should also state it's gawk-specific due to `delete a`.

Comment: @EdMorton - Thanks for the information and your posted answer.  Good stuff!  While I don't know the origins of the awk on my mac (whether it's gawk underneath), it has delete for arrays and array elements in it's man pages and `which gawk` returns nothing.  I'll keep the indexing in mind.  I program in C a lot, so 0 or 1 starts don't bother me, and I thought that `<` performed slightly better than `<=` (though here it clearly wouldn't matter).  I can understand that you'd like to present consistency for the language though.

Comment: Yeah, I believe some non-gawks might support `delete array` too but others don't, I should probably have said non-POSIX instead of `gawk-only`. The `0 or 1` array index start thing is particularly important for C programmers to grasp/adopt. I'd been programming in C for about 10 years before I started using awk and then the number of times I got bit by calling split() or similar to populate an array and then started my indexing at zero doesn't bear thinking about!

Comment: I really appreciated your answer @n0741337, but Ed's is more betterer.. Thank you so much though. :)

Comment: No worries - I learned something from his answer.  However, be advised that both the non-gawk variants he mentioned left extra blank lines in the output for me when there was more than one matching block.