# pipe to less if input is not empty

Tags: bash, gawk

In an earlier question ([Use awk to output section of file forward and back from target regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21470992/use-awk-to-output-section-of-file-forward-and-back-from-target-regex)) I developed the following statement that pipes output from gawk into less.

```
gawk -v RS="${recordSetDelimiter}" "BEGIN{IGNORECASE=$ignoreCase} /${searchTerm}/{print FILENAME ORS \$0 ORS \"<<\"}" "${directory}"/*.idx | less -I -p "${searchTermLess}"
```

However, I want the ability to avoid less if the input is empty. I thought about variables or temp text files, and I guess this could work, but the input might be big and I am not sure how that would affect handling. (Since what I love about this command is just how quick it is.)

Is there a "best way" to handle this? How to also handle input that is just empty lines?

Comment: How about using the `-F` option? This causes it to exit immediately if the input fits on one screen. If the input is empty, this will happen.

Comment: My goodness that was easy. Please put this as an answer so that I can recognise it as such!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `-F` option to `less`.

```
gawk -v RS="${recordSetDelimiter}" "BEGIN{IGNORECASE=$ignoreCase} /${searchTerm}/{print FILENAME ORS \$0 ORS \"<<\"}" "${directory}"/*.idx |
    less -F -I -p "${searchTermLess}"
```

This makes it exit immediately if the output would fit on one screen, which is trivially true if there's no output.